# Difference between Search Dialog and Search Widget Android

Tags: android, android-widget, search-dialog

I want to know the difference between Search Dialog and Search Widget in Android. I know how to implement each of them with code but don't know difference in terms of looks, behaviors etc. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

**The search dialog** is a UI component that's controlled by the Android system. When activated by the user, the search dialog appears at the top of the activity.

**The search widget** is an instance of SearchView that you can place anywhere in your layout. By default, the search widget behaves like a standard EditText widget and doesn't do anything, but you can configure it so that the Android system handles all input events, delivers queries to the appropriate activity, and provides search suggestions

Comment: ketankk just copied the documentation from deveoper site we need some image